# Ugly iphone scrollbar, uneditable

Tags: css, iphone

On several of my pages I have this thick ugly scroll bar popping up when it's never happening on otehr pages.

It's quite weird as I don't reference the ::-webkit-scrollbar in any way. Has anyone had a similar issue?

The weirdest thing is, it's a Shopify theme and all pages use the same file. But only on the cart do we get this ugly scroll bar.

http://www.eightsleep.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are inline styles in the HTML of your Cart page. They show on line 722 for me when I View Source on /cart:

```
<style>
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 8px;
        background-color: #C3C3C3;
        border: 2px solid #eee;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
</style>
```